# how to change the width of the header on blogspot.com?

Tags: html, css, web, blogger

http://znobio.blogspot.com/2017/06/blog-post_14.html here is the page I'm interested in. Basically, the title "ZNOBIO" on the top left corner is not in the right position while scrolling. What should I do to fix this? Can I somehow change the width of the header and if I can - where?

Answer (score 1):

Login to your Blogger dashboard>Theme>Edit HTML.

Place this following codes just above `]]></b:skin>` tag

`#Header1.widget.Header {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}`

To find `]]></b:skin>` tag press **CTRL** + **F** on your keyboard and then copy and paste `]]></b:skin>` into the search box and press **Enter**.

Now you are good to go. You can also work with the `.titlewrapper: margin-top: 7px;` to move the title upward or downward.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the `margin-top` value to -18px on the div `.titlewrapper`, or to another value if you want to be more precise on its position, on the css stylesheet. (Found this value using Mozilla Firefox. The result might differ according to your browser.)

Comment: instead of using text go with header logo. blogger can automatically resize your image when you use mobile too..